# JavaScript OOP Models Formula

Tags: javascript, oop, model-view-controller

Working on creating a dirt simply MVC framework for one of my own projects. Rather than using one that is public, I decided to create one since my needs are very unusual.

I've got my structure down for the Controllers and Views, however, I'm having some issues creating my model structure.

This is what I have for my model structure:

```
model.models = function(args){

    init: function(){

        this.on_init();
    },

    on_init: args.on_init || noop,
    data: args.data || {},

};
```

So then, I would call this as a basic formula for all of the models I want to create. For example, I want to create employees, notifications and some other models using this as a basic blueprint, then make some basic adjustments.

I call:

```
model.employees = new model.models({

    on_init: function(){
        //something specific
    },

    data: {
        //defaults
    }

});
```

And we're all good up to this point, but **here is where I'm having troubles.** Now, when I want to create my end result, the model, I cannot create a new object from an object.. it must be a function.

The only thing I can think of is creating a return function for the second method, but that renders some issues in itself. I have done some research looking at other MVC code, but I was unable to wrap my head around it.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I think the best thing you could do is use something like backbone.js, ember.js, or another will documented Javascript MVC/MV* framework. You could learn a lot from using them, reading their docs, and looking into their source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a lot of fiddling, came up with this:

```
var blueprint = function(args){

return {

    data: args.data,
    on_init: args.on_init,
    create: function(args){

        this.on_init();

        return {

            data: this.data,

            whatever: function(){
                console.log(args);
            }
        };
    }

};

};

var notifs = new blueprint({

on_init: function(){
    console.log('init');
},

data: {
    test: 'test'
}

});

var res = notifs.create('test');

console.log(blueprint);
console.log(notifs);
console.log(res);
```

It comes out with a main function that works, the notifs function is customizable for each individual object type, then calling the create method will create the end method.

Boom!

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want ?

```
model.models = function(args){
    var noop = function(){};

    var o = {};
    var init = args.on_init || noop;
    var data = args.data || {};

    init();
    //handle other initialization
    //o.a = xx;
    //o.b = xx;
    //o.c = data.xxx;
    //....

    return o;
}
```

then you can use the new, and it can't appear syntax error

Comment: I don't see any change other than adding an a new variable "o" to do the return? It's basically the exact same as the question?